# AMQP Channel shutdown but Consumer not always restart

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a frequent `Channel shutdown: connection error` issues (under `24.133.241:5671` thread, name is truncated) in RabbitMQ Java client (my producer and consumer are far apart). Most of the time consumer is automatically restarted as I have enabled heartbeat (15 seconds). However, there were some instances only `Channel shutdown: connection error` but no `Consumer raised exception` and no `Restarting Consumer` (under `cTaskExecutor-4` thread).

My current workaround is to restart my application. Anyone can shed some light on this matter?

```
2017-03-20 12:42:38.856 ERROR 24245 --- [24.133.241:5671] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory
      : Channel shutdown: connection error
2017-03-20 12:42:39.642  WARN 24245 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerCont
ainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports
it
...
2017-03-20 12:42:39.642  INFO 24245 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerCont
ainer : Restarting Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-4CqrRsUP8plDpLQdNcOjDw=21-05060179}], channel=Ca
ched Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://21-05060179@10.24.133.241:5671/,1), conn: Proxy@7ec317
54 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@44bac9ec [delegate=amqp://21-05060179@10.24.133
.241:5671/], acknowledgeMode=NONE local queue size=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, this is due to the consumer thread being "stuck" in user code somewhere, so it can't react to the broken connection.

If you have network issues, perhaps it's stuck reading or writing to a socket; make sure you have timeouts set for any I/O operations.

Next time it happens take a thread dump to see what the consumer threads are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any existing rabbitmq setting I can enable/tune to reduce the issue?

Comment: No; as I said, it's generally a problem with user code; if a listener is stuck, there is noting the framework (or RabbitMQ) can do; you need a thread dump to figure out what the problem is.